# PostgreSQL Autocommit efficiency on SELECT queries

Tags: postgresql, performance, autocommit

I am using Psycopg2 to issue many `SELECT` queries to my Postgres DB. These queries have a small size result and they are sent at a high frequency.

In order to avoid managing transactions myself (because I'm lazy), I have set `autocommit = True` in the session settings.

Edit: there is no long pause between queries, no data manipulation, and the cursor gets closed immediately after I stop making queries.

I would like to know: When issuing `SELECT` queries at a high frequency, is there any performance penalty of using autocommit?

Using Postgres 9.6 and Psycopg 2.7.7. And *yes*, I am using prepared statements.

Comment: Actually, doing so is good, because you don't keep "idle" transactions around.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Indeed, this was the rationale behind initially enabling autocommit, as recommended in the PsycoPG docs. However, my transactions only perform Select queries and there is no long pause between queries. Likewise, the transaction would be closed immediately after it becomes useless. Hence I thought it might be a special case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Autocommit is the right thing because:

- There is no performance penalty because a read-only transaction does not have to write to the transaction log (WAL).
- No locks are held, like a_horse_with_no_name commented. Even a `SELECT` holds a n `ACCESS SHARE` lock on the table, which will block commands like `TRUNCATE`, `DROP TABLE` and vacuum truncation.
- The driver doesn't have to send those extra `BEGIN` and `COMMIT` statements, which will cause unnecessary client-server round trips.